# Query for places objects within max distance stored as a field

Tags: parse-platform

I have an object that has a field with "max coverage distance".
I want to query a list of the above objects that "cover" the user's location according to their each variable "max coverage distance" value.

For example:

- Let's say the query'd object is police stations (PFObject).
- Each police station has a circular coverage radius of 3km (stored in the "max coverage distance" field), so everything that at less than 3km distance is "covered".
- This distance may vary from one police station instance to the other.
- Let's also say I have a "current user" with its location (PFGeoPoint).

Now, I want to get all the police stations that cover my current user's location, i.e. that the user's location is not farther than 3km away from each station.

The normal `[PFQuery wherekey:withinKilometers:]` won't work, as the value I would give to the withinKilometers parameter is stored inside the object I'm querying.

In SQL (which I already forgot) I'd do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM PoliceStations WHERE WithinKilometers({given_user_location}, PoliceStations.maxCoverageDistance)=TRUE
```

Obviously one way to do it is query for all of the police stations and then go one by one and remove the ones that aren't covering according to their max distance field and the user's location.

Any idea how to achieve it in a better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after searching even further it appears that it's not yet supported.
Not even sure if it should be :)

Straight forward method works, let it be it.